# Azure project location

Tags: azure

if any one changes his project location from F:siteroot/example folder to C://example ,
because there is less space to run project inside the siteroot folder.

Then what type of problem may created .?
Is there are any security related problem ?

Thanks and regards
Alok dixit.

Comment: You changed project location in your Visual Studio Solution ? If that's the case, it's not gonna matter in any way once you package and deploy it to the cloud.

Comment: i am talking about the location of the project on azure not for the local visual studio.after deploying the projects it's all goes inside the "siteroot" folder but i want to changed the projects from siteroot to another drive folder.....

Answer (score 0):

As Lescai lonel said in his comment - assuming you're asking about any impact to the solution once deployed on Azure - there wouldn't be any - the solution is compiled and packaged in what is effectively a zip file, it then gets uploaded to Azure and deployed on the VM to a fixed location, irrespective of where it was on your development environment.

Comment: i am talking about the location of the project on azure not for the local visual studio.after deploying the projects it's all goes inside the "siteroot" folder but i want to changed the projects from siteroot to another drive folder.....

Comment: I'm curious as you why you would want to move the location on Azure? You say there's less space in this location - have you actually faced space issues? what's taking all that space?

Answer (score 0):

I wont matter to the project if the files are placed on c: or f: but beware if you have set up source control since this will create a workspace associated with the project(assuming tfs at least).